# How to hide elevate zoom outside scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, elevatezoom

I'm using elevate zoom so that whenever it is hovered over a image it show us a zoomed portion of a part of image. In my project the image is inside a scroll. When applying elevate zoom outside the scroll also its being projected. so my question is how to hide it. Here is a sample fiddle of the problem am facing.

**Problem Demo**

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tabsheerabdulla/jd181oz9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Image Constrain ElevateZoom</h1>
<div class="scroll">
<img id="zoom_01" src='https://www.guthriegreen.com/sites/default/files/Kung-Fu-Panda-6%5B1%5D.jpg' data-zoom-image="https://www.guthriegreen.com/sites/default/files/Kung-Fu-Panda-6%5B1%5D.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#zoom_01 {
  width: 400px;
  }
  .scroll {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
```

**Javascript**

```
 $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({ zoomType: "lens", containLensZoom: true, gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active"});
```

Comment: You can't scroll while it's being zoomed. Why the scroll bars then? Also, it doesn't make much sense for the user to have to scroll to see more of the image in this scenario.

Comment: Here u can scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/tabsheerabdulla/jd181oz9/6/. Our project uses long protrait images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width of Image for example:
    img id="zoom_01" style="width:200px" ...
and set proper width of Scroll Div for example 
    div style="width:400px"class="scroll"..

Comment: can u fiddle?? so that i can have a proper understanding.